# Decrypt SQL Server Database with AES encryption

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited a database where some of the columns are encrypted using an AES Rfc2898DeriveBytes decryption with a 32 bit key and a 16 bit IV.  Here is part of the code that does the decrypt from a C# class:

```
public string Decrypt(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        return value;
    }
    if (_key == null)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Configuration.GetSection("Encryption").GetSection("decryptionKey").Value, new byte[] { [salt value] });
        _key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        _iv = pdb.GetBytes(16);
    }
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value.Trim());

    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        if (encryptor != null)
        {
            encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(_key, _iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                value = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

I removed the salt value, but this is the method which is the value in the database is decrypted in the C# class.  Is there a way to create a UDF similar to this in SQL Server that we can call with specified column values to get the decrypted value?  Right now I have to call the database, grab the value, and use a utility to decrypt it.  This makes it really difficult to see values in the database when we need to view the data in queries.  If I could create a function to call with the columns we want to see unencrypted in the database without having to do this one at a time it would have a lot of time for us.  I have the decryption keys and validation keys.

Comment: Why do you need to do in SQL Server?  You have frw other choices 1) Do it from a SQLCMD.EXE which is a command line utility that is part of SQL Server.  You can create a batch file that does the query and the decryption 2) The Power Shell has internally the SQLCMD.EXE and you can do everything in the Power Shell Script. 3) Create a Windows Form project which output the query results to a DGV.

Comment: I did look on the site with no success.  @jdweng it looks like I will be taking option 3 with some modifications.  Instead of a windows form, I am creating a REST API that we can pass in the name of the table to decrypt and return the results that way.  I was hoping to call .net methods from within sql server.  I thought I had heard that was possible, but I think I was mistaken.